# Is there a way to make R help prompt(with Tab) includes descriptions of all parameters of certain function ( like in Java Doc)?

Tags: r, package

It's inconvinience when I press tab to see how to use parameters of a certain function as in Java Doc in Eclipse, e.g. plot(), and find out there's no descriptions given for some parameters(see figure below). Is it that I didn't install some package providing the complete descriptions of them? Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: Have a look at `?rc.settings` in particular the section Completion of function arguments:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get some idea of the arguments to a function with `args`.  Here's an example that describes the arguments of the function `strsplit`

```
> args(strsplit)
# function (x, split, fixed = FALSE, perl = FALSE, useBytes = FALSE) 
# NULL
```

The above call to `args` shows the arguments to `strsplit`, and their default settings.

If the function is a *closure* (see `?closure`), a named list of its formal arguments can be seen with `formals`. View a default setting quickly with the `$` operator

```
> formals(strsplit)$perl
# [1] FALSE
```

Other information viewable in the console is available by simply entering the function name itself.

```
> strsplit
# function (x, split, fixed = FALSE, perl = FALSE, useBytes = FALSE) 
# .Internal(strsplit(x, as.character(split), fixed, perl, useBytes))
# <bytecode: 0x26d3388>
# <environment: namespace:base>
```

---

Now, `plot` is a bit different. Since we can't tell a lot about the arguments from

```
> plot
# function (x, y, ...) 
# UseMethod("plot")
# <bytecode: 0x333a750>
# <environment: namespace:graphics>
```

we can see that it uses `methods`.  Use `methods(plot)` and see the different methods. Taking `plot.default` for example, we can view its R source code with

```
> plot.default
```

and a more detailed set of arguments with

```
> args(plot.default)
# function (x, y = NULL, type = "p", xlim = NULL, ylim = NULL, 
#           log = "", main = NULL, sub = NULL, xlab = NULL, ylab = NULL, 
#           ann = par("ann"), axes = TRUE, frame.plot = axes, panel.first = NULL, 
#           panel.last = NULL, asp = NA, ...) 
#   NULL
```

---

For functions that are in an *installed package*, you can view some of its information with `::`, used as `package::function`.  For example, for the `str_extract` function in the `stringr` package,

```
> stringr::str_extract
# function (string, pattern) 
# {
#     string <- check_string(string)
#     pattern <- check_pattern(pattern, string)
#     positions <- str_locate(string, pattern)
#     str_sub(string, positions[, "start"], positions[, "end"])
# }
# <environment: namespace:stringr>
```

There is so much more about this topic in the pdfs [*R Internals*](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html) and [*Writing R Extensions*](http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/r-project/arch/sun4x_59/lib/R/doc/manual/R-exts.html).

Comment: woww, thx for help, I was only able to use such commands as ?<functionname>.

Comment: Ah, no problem.  These are just a few of the *"hidden"* gems in R that can save a programmer a ton of time.  There is so much more. I would suggest reading [*R Internals*](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html) and [*Writing R Extensions*](http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/r-project/arch/sun4x_59/lib/R/doc/manual/R-exts.html)

Answer (score 4):

You can try [RStudio IDE](https://www.rstudio.com/ide/). By typing a function, say, `plot()`, and then press tab, you can see a list of arguments with a brief description. After that, by pressing `F1`, you can see addition help. I think that satisfies what you need.

Comment: I tried, but there're some parameters' descriptions that are not shown. E.g. plot()'s "ci=".

Comment: @macchiavalley that's right. However, if you see the help document, the parameters which have descriptions will be listed in the `Arguments` section. Try `summary()` and you'll see only three arguments (object, maxsum and digits) are available with help docs.

Comment: probably a little advanced, but these parameters, when the authors write package, have `@param` documented.

Comment: Only if they use roxygen to generate the documentation.

Comment: I think this has less to do with roxygen (which after all is just a preprocessor for the actual Rd files) but more with the method dispatch governing which plot() or summary() you get.